# Is It Possible To Convert a Comp Type to Int64 or Display a Comp value As a String With Commas

Tags: delphi

I have an event in a component (VCLZip) that uses the comp type, but to display the result as a string I think I need to convert the comp value to int64, but I can not find a way to do so.  **Is there a way to convert a comp value to int64? or is there a different way to display a comp value as a string with commas ... maybe Format?**

```
function FormatKBSize( Bytes: Cardinal ): string;
{ Converts a numeric value into a string that represents the number expressed as a size value in kilobytes. }
var
arrSize: array [ 0 .. 255 ] of char;
begin
   { explorer style }
   Result := '';
   { same formating used in the Size column of Explorer in detailed mode }
   Result := ShLwApi.StrFormatKBSizeW( Bytes, arrSize, Length( arrSize ) - 1 );
 end;

procedure TFormMain.VCLZip1StartZipInfo( Sender: TObject; NumFiles: Integer; TotalBytes: Comp;
  var EndCentralRecord: TEndCentral; var StopNow: Boolean );
var
  Tb: int64;
begin
  InfoWin.Lines.Add( '' );
  InfoWin.Lines.Add( 'Number of files to be zipped: ' + IntToStr( NumFiles ) + '...' );
  Tb := TotalBytes; // <= this will not compile
  Tb := Int64(TotalBytes); // <= this will not compile
  InfoWin.Lines.Add( 'Total bytes to process: ' + FormatKBSize( Tb ) + '...' );
 end;
```

**Edit - this seems to work but is there a better way?**

```
InfoWin.Lines.Add( Format( '%n', [  TotalBytes ] ) );
```

Comment: Comp is a floating point value (but integer 64 compatible). Try use Round(TotalBytes).

Comment: ALWAYS report what **actual** errors you obtain. "This won't compile" is not an error message. It's just a way to delay any useful answer, or receive no help at all.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, seems like a perfectly valid question to me. +1

Comment: `Tb := TotalBytes` and the following statement are making little sense, while message accompanying "wont compile" error explains a lot. Moreover, selecting this message and pressing F1 yields an explanation and resolution recipe. Not my downvote but really could be.

Comment: @user539484 `Tb := TotalBytes` makes perfect sense. The question is why it is so hard to assign a `Comp` to an `Int64`.

Comment: Guess it's because of the type compatibility and assignment rules. You can assign an integer to a real, but not viceversa. TotalBytes := Tb would work. IMHO the compiler should tread Comp in a different way, but I guess it never got much attention. Also I wonder why the cast doesn't work, but the documentation tells casting a real to an integer is explicitly not allowed. I'd expect it to work and let me read that memory as it was an integer of a given size. There's the trick to declare a record and use it to cast a real to whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Comp type is an integer type but it is classified as a real. Thereby the compiler may not allow you to cast it directly to an Int64, nor assign it. You have to convert it. Try to use Trunc() to convert it to an Integer type.

You may also try to use the **absolute** directive to have an Int64 variable share the same address as the Comp variable:

```
procedure TFormMain.VCLZip1StartZipInfo( Sender: TObject; NumFiles: Integer; TotalBytes: Comp; 
  var EndCentralRecord: TEndCentral; var StopNow: Boolean ); 
var 
  Tb: Int64 absolute TotalBytes;
```

It should work although I usually don't like it too much because a cast/conversion is easy to spot in code, an absolute declaration may not be seen easily if the code is long enough.

A third solution is to declare a record:

```
CompRec = record
  I64: Int64;
end;
```

and then the cast works:

```
Tb := CompRec(TotalBytes).I64;
```

Comment: The absolute keyword works ok. The memory footprint of Comp is the same as Int64, only the operations of Comp are made in the FPU.

Comment: Ok, here's a quote from [Merlyn's](http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/pas-real.htm) place : The Floating Point Unit (FPU) of a PC has, in addition to the three IEEE-standard true floating-point types single, double, and extended, a type without an exponent, comp, which takes only integer values.

Comment: I guess that's just a compiler enforced rule, the processor itself does not force anything. Comps are loaded into the FPU to be managed, but assigning them to an Int64 when they're in memory and not in the FPU registers could work without going through the FPU as long as their memory layout is the same (as it is). IIRC Delphi introduced the Comp type before Int64 and because it was rarely used no optimization was made in the compiler to treat it a little different from the other real types

Comment: The Comp type was introduced in the Turbo Pascal days. Support for 32 and 64 bit integer operations were not well optimized/supported at that time.

Comment: int64 is only something from D4 times iirc. Before COMP was used. Finding comp usage is a code smell (it screams OOOOLLLLDDD!!!)

Answer (score 2):

Whoever wrote VCLZip to use `Comp` should get a slap on the wrist for that.  `Comp` is an old Object Pascal 64-bit Integer type.  The author should have used `Int64` instead.  Even (older) Delphi documentation says as much:

> The Comp (computational) type is native to the Intel CPU and
>   represents a 64-bit integer. It is classified as a real, however,
>   because it does not behave like an ordinal type. (For example, you
>   cannot increment or decrement a Comp value.) Comp is maintained for
>   backwards compatibility only. Use the Int64 type for better
>   performance.

To convert a `Comp` to an `Int64`, you have to convert the `Comp` to a `Double` first (which the compiler does support), then convert the `Double` to `Int64`.

Comment: Unless VCLZip was written before the Int64 type became available in Delphi, or if it still supports versions of Delphi where Int64 is not available. Time to get rid of it, though. Especially since it is an Intel CPU native type, but requires FPU calls to work.

Comment: `Int64` was introduced in Delphi 4. According to VCLZip's homepage, (http://vclzip.bizland.com/), Delphi 4 is the earliest version still supported.

Comment: I have much worse opinion about VCLZip author. Standard ZIP file header dedicates 4 bytes to store number of bytes. `Int64` is bogus for this purpose too.